# Pandas merging mixed length datasets without duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge several mixed dataframes, with some missing values which sometimes exist in other dataframes to one combined dataset, some dataframes also might contain extra columns, then those should be added and all other rows have NaN as values.

This based on one or several columns, the row index has no meaning, the true dataset has many columns so manually removing anything is very much less than desirable.

So essentially, merging several dataframes based on one or several columns, prioritizing any non NaN value, or if two conflicting non NaN values would exist then prioritize the existing value in the base dataframe and not the one being merged in.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 4],
    'data_one': [np.nan, 3, np.nan], 
    'data_two': [4, np.nan, np.nan], 
})
   id  data_one  data_two
0   1       NaN       4.0
1   2       3.0       NaN
2   4       NaN       NaN

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 3],
    'data_one': [8, np.nan], 
    'data_two': [np.nan, 4], 
    'data_three': [np.nan, 100]
})
   id  data_one  data_two  data_three
0   1       8.0       NaN         NaN
1   3       NaN       4.0       100.0


# Desired result
res = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'data_one': [8, 3, np.nan, np.nan], 
    'data_two': [4, np.nan, 4, np.nan], 
    'data_three': [np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan], 
})
   id  data_one  data_two  data_three
0   1       8.0       4.0         NaN
1   2       3.0       NaN         NaN
2   3       NaN       4.0       100.0
3   4       NaN       NaN         NaN
```

The functions I have been experimenting with so far is `pd.merge()`, `pd.join()`, `pd.combine_first()` but haven't had any success, maybe missing something easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a `groupby()` coupled with `fillna()`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

results in:

```
    id   data_one   data_two    data_three
0   1    8.0        4.0         NaN
1   2    3.0        NaN         NaN
1   3    NaN        4.0         100.0
2   4    NaN        NaN         NaN
```

Note that it is gonna return separate rows for the positions where df1 and df2 both have a non-null values. Which is intentional since I don't know what you want to do with in such cases.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick, took some hours to run but still quick enough to be manageable without multiprocessing!